# Google Drive SDK Update sharing permissions to private

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I like to update the permission of a document from anyone with the link to private, to set the permission to (anyone with the link) use this and works:

```
newPermission.setType("anyone");
newPermission.setWithLink(true);
newPermission.setRole("reader");
```

but trying to set the permission to private is not working, i'm using this :

```
newPermission.setType("user");
newPermission.setValue("me");
newPermission.setRole("owner");
```

the response is this

```
500 Internal Server Error

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

What are the parameters that i have to pass to set the permissions to private ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of the document? If not, you can not set yourself as owner. If you are, then the list of permissions for the document will have two entries, one for you as owner and another one to make everyone else a reader. Find the latter and delete it, and you should be all set.